# Can't find references (xref) to function

Tags: ida, c++

I am reversing a function and when I trying to see its references, it doesn't show me the calls to the function. It only show the place of the object in RVA.
[image]

Is there a plug-in or something that I can find all the call to this function?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be an indirect call to the function? Like described [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18930/ida-function-never-called-and-only-cross-referenced-as-data)
One of the suggestions is to search for cross-references to that data area you found. For example off_.... looks suspicious.